# Problems in Parcelable Class using a List of Custom Objects (Defined in an Inner Class)

Tags: java, android, exception, parcelable

I'm trying to make my class Parcelable, but I keep getting these errors:

```
    08-28 07:42:55.598    7810-7810/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3617)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17620)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3612)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17620)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlan$SubPlan)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1279)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1233)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:622)
        at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlan.writeToParcel(CropRotationPlan.java:248)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1627)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
        at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6850)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1908)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1483)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3388)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3349)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
        at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlannerActivity.btnViewPlan(CropRotationPlannerActivity.java:197)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3612)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17620)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlan
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1274)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1233)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:622)
            at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlan.writeToParcel(CropRotationPlan.java:248)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
            at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1627)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
            at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6850)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1908)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1483)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3388)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3349)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
            at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlannerActivity.btnViewPlan(CropRotationPlannerActivity.java:197)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3612)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17620)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's the structure of my class; it has an inner class. I don't think it's ideal to put my entire code. It's just too long.

```
public class CropRotationPlan implements Parcelable {

    String name; // Name of plan
    HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>> listOfFamilies; // HashMap containing Plant Family Names as keys and a List of plants
    List<SubPlan> listOfSubPlans;

    public CropRotationPlan() {
        name = null;
        listOfFamilies = new HashMap<>();
        listOfSubPlans = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeSerializable(this.listOfFamilies);
        dest.writeList(this.listOfSubPlans);
    }

    protected CropRotationPlan(Parcel in) {
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.listOfFamilies = (HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>>) in.readSerializable();
        this.listOfSubPlans = new ArrayList<SubPlan>();
        in.readList(this.listOfSubPlans, List.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<CropRotationPlan> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<CropRotationPlan>() {
        public CropRotationPlan createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new CropRotationPlan(source);
        }

        public CropRotationPlan[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CropRotationPlan[size];
        }
    };

    public class SubPlan implements Serializable {
        int year;
        HashMap<String, Integer> orderOfFamilies;
        ...
    }
}
```

At this point, I seriously have no idea what to do.

`CropRotationPlan.java:248` is `dest.writeList(this.listOfSubPlans);` in `writeToParcel()`

Also, in another class, I have this method:

```
public void btnViewPlan(View view) {
    // We'll be sending our cropRotationPlan object to next activity (PlanActivity)
    // And we'll be expecting a result (since we'll allow the user to manipulate the object there)
    Intent i = new Intent(CropRotationPlannerActivity.this, PlanActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("cropRotationPlan", cropRotationPlan);
    startActivityForResult(i, SET_PLAN_REQUEST);
}
```

`CropRotationPlannerActivity.java:197` is: `startActivityForResult(i, SET_PLAN_REQUEST);`

I've tried placing my inner class into a separate class, and then had it to implement `Serializable` OR `Parcelable` (just one of 'em) but I just keep getting errors. All relating to my `SubPlan` class; like problems with marshing it and stuff. Along with using `TypedList` instead somewhere in the code.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I just don't know what to do anymore.

PS: I'm sorry if I sound so incoherent right now. I might edit this post once I recover my sanity.

**CODE FOR `SubPlan` CLASS**

```
public class SubPlan implements Serializable {
        int year;
        HashMap<String, Integer> orderOfFamilies;

        public SubPlan(int year) {
            orderOfFamilies = new HashMap<>();
            this.year = year;
            int temp = -1;
            for (String key : listOfFamilies.keySet()) {
                orderOfFamilies.put(key, ++temp);
            }
        }

        public SubPlan(int year, HashMap<String, Integer> orderOfFamilies) {
            this.year = year;
            this.orderOfFamilies = orderOfFamilies;
        }

        public int getYear() {
            return year;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "Year " + year;
        }

        public String getKey(int index) {
            for (String key : orderOfFamilies.keySet()) {
                if (orderOfFamilies.get(key).equals(index))
                    return key;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public int getLocationOf(String family) {
            return orderOfFamilies.get(family);
        }

        public void setOrderOfFamily(String family, int index) {
            if (orderOfFamilies.containsKey(family))
                orderOfFamilies.put(family, index);
        }

        public void removeFamily(String family) {
            if (orderOfFamilies.containsKey(family)) {
                orderOfFamilies.remove(family);
            }
        }

        public void rotateFamilies() {
            for (int i = 0; i < getNumberOfFamilies(); i++) {
                String family = getKey(i);
                // if not last family on list
                if (orderOfFamilies.get(family) != getNumberOfFamilies() - 1)
                    setOrderOfFamily(family, i + 1);
                else
                    setOrderOfFamily(family, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Additionally, `getNumberOfFamilies()` is a method belonging to the parent class, with the following definition:

```
    public int getNumberOfFamilies() {
        return listOfFamilies.size();
    }
```

I have initially not let `SubPlan` implement `Serializable` and these are the exceptions I get:

```
    08-28 08:31:07.809    8741-8741/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3617)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17620)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3612)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17620)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlan$SubPlan@4191f010
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1235)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:622)
            at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlan.writeToParcel(CropRotationPlan.java:249)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
            at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1627)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
            at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6850)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1908)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1483)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3388)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3349)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
            at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlannerActivity.btnViewPlan(CropRotationPlannerActivity.java:197)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3612)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17620)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-28 08:31:09.543     531-1643/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '41d34990 thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb/thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-28 08:31:09.543     531-1643/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '4281f970 thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb/thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlannerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Additionally, I have tried implementing `Parcelable` on `SubPlan` and made it have its own class:

```
08-28 08:54:59.291    9245-9245/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3617)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17620)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3612)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17620)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.io.SerializationHandleMap.get(SerializationHandleMap.java:63)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.dumpCycle(ObjectOutputStream.java:425)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1566)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1015)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1053)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
        at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:644)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1053)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1016)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1053)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1274)
        at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlan.writeToParcel(CropRotationPlan.java:185)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
        at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.SubPlan.writeToParcel(SubPlan.java:83)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1017)
        at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlan.writeToParcel(CropRotationPlan.java:186)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
        at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.SubPlan.writeToParcel(SubPlan.java:83)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1017)
        at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlan.writeToParcel(CropRotationPlan.java:186)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
        at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.SubPlan.writeToParcel(SubPlan.java:83)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1017)
        at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlan.write
```

Comment: I would like to keep it as an inner class, as much as possible.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the SubPlan's implementation of Serializable. Could you include that code?

Comment: Mike is correct, you have a primitive in that class meaning it is not serializable. Change it to a parcelable

Comment: @Stimsoni: Do you mean my inner class? I have tried to place it as a separate class and made it implement Parcelable yet I still get errors. I'll post the results.

Comment: Have a look at SubPlan. It contains a field called 'year' which is a primitive. This will stop the class from being serialized properly. If you change it to parcelable so that it can be marshalled properly. 

I'd try to keep away from using serializable as well. Apart from it being slow parcelables are more explicit so you can actually see what and how each field is being used

Comment: Andreas does bring up a point as well. If the inner class doesn't need access to the outer class it should be marked as static otherwise it will have an implicit instance that isn't required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *root cause* is listed at the bottom, and the error says it all:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlan
```

The class `CropRotationPlan` must be [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

**Update**

Because `SubPlan` is *not* `static`, serializing `SubPlan` also means serializing the outer class `CropRotationPlan`. Since only the `SubPlan` constructor seems to use the outer class, change the class to `static` and send `listOfFamilies` in as a parameter on the constructor.

Comment: I tried doing that, but it did not solve my problem.